# How to form Hashmap with list of values for a single key in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am getting `Employee DOB` and `Department name` from database. Then I am processing `DOB` to get the age using.

```
Map<String,ArrayList<Integer>> emp = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>()

          while(rs.next()){ 

            //rs is resultset of DB Query               
            String dob = rs.getString(1);
            //Calculating age in variable age
        age = age of employee from DOB

    emp = addIntoMap(emp,rs.getString(2),age);

        }

    public Map<String, List<Integer>> addIntoMap(Map<String, List<Integer>> emp, String key, Integer value) {
        List<Integer> list = emp.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            emp.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(value);
    return emp;

    }
```

Now I want to construct and HashMap of type `<Department_Name,ArrayList<Age of emplyees>>`. Here the dperamtnet_name is the key and for each key I want list of age of employees

I know that using `Map<String,ArrayList<Integer>> emp = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>()` I can construct a multi hashmap but how do I put the age values for each key?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own method to add the elements in the map:

```
public void addIntoMap(Map<String, List<Integer>> emp, String key, Integer value) {
    List<Integer> list = emp.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        emp.put(key, list);
    }
    list.add(value);
}
```

If you don't want/need to deal with these problems, use [`MultiMap`](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Guava.

Comment: Is `innerMap` a typo? Did you mean `emp`?

Comment: @Joffrey code fixed. It was *adapted* from a previous answer of me.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have updated the code above.Is it correct and will it work?

Comment: @user2966197 why are you creating the `Map` on every iteration? If you do that, you will lose the data per iteration. Move the `Map` declaration above the `while`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry that was a typo. Is it correct now?

Comment: I have a doubt. when this function is called for first time(Key is not present), then inside function list will be `null` for `if` statement and then `new arraylist` will be created and it is then inserted into `emp`.But list will still be empty wouldn't it? so will it be that for key S the list will be empty?shouldn't I use `emp.put(key,list)` after `list.add(value)` also

Comment: @user2966197 no. Again: **test it**.

Comment: The output is not correct.Don't you think that we are using emp.put() only when list is empty.But when list is not empty, then we are not doing emp.put()

Comment: @user2966197 that's not the problem. The list is already `put` when you initialize it. The code should work fine. You have to debug through your code to check where's the error.

Comment: but we are using `put` when list is null so an empty list is added to the hashmap.we are adding `value` to the `list` after the if condition and not doing any `put` then

Comment: That code is tested in production live system and works as expected. Your problem is somewhere else.